# More than one document for one post... any ideas?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, join

```
SELECT
    `posts`.`id`,
    `posts`.`created_at`,
    `posts`.`content`,
    `posts`.`replies`,
    `groups`.`id` AS `group_id`,
    `groups`.`name` AS `group_name`,
    `users`.`id` AS `user_id`,
    `users`.`name`,
    `users`.`surname`,
    `users`.`avatar`,
    `posts`.`link`,
    `posts`.`event_id`,
    `events`.`name` AS `event_name`,
    `docs`.`id` AS `attachment_id`
FROM `posts`
JOIN `groups`
    ON (`groups`.`id` = `posts`.`group_id`)
JOIN `users`
    ON (`users`.`id` = `posts`.`user_id`)
LEFT JOIN `events`
    ON (`events`.`id` = `posts`.`event_id`)
LEFT JOIN `docs`
    ON (`docs`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id`)
WHERE `posts`.`post_id` = 0
    AND `posts`.`group_id` = '28'
ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 4
OFFSET 0
```

This query selects posts for current group. Last thing I need to add is that it selects documents (`docs`) that are related to that post...

```
...
`docs`.`id` AS `attachment_id`
...
LEFT JOIN `docs`
    ON (`docs`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id`)
...
```

I will need `hashed_name` and `name` from `docs` table. At the moment, it selects only `id`, but its not the biggest problem. Problem is that one post may have more that one docs related to it.

In that case, in `docs` table `id` (primary keys) aren't the same, but `post_id` (so its related to that post) are. For now, if post have more than one attachment, I get 'n' entries back... so I have like duplicate posts. That's the problem.

The goal is to, afterwards, loop trough array like this:

```
<?php

    if(!empty($posts)) {

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            echo $post['content'];

            foreach ($post['docs'] as $doc) {
                echo $doc['name'];
                echo $doc['hashed_name'];
            }
        }

    }

?>
```

How to modify query to get that result? Thanks in advice!

Comment: Why not use another query for fetching the docs AFTER you fetch the post? it doesn't seem logical to me that you'd want one row with multiple documents

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky Is that slow to have 2 queries? I can do it... Hmmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reorganize the array. You are always going to get back a flat result so youll actually have every doc+post+event... you need need to loop through the result an then organize them into a nested structure by whatever you want the primary record to be (in this case the post).

Comment: So query is okey... I just need to reorganize array in PHP side? That's easy!

Comment: exactly. but depending on the size of your result set its possibel you could run into memory issues... but i guess cross that bridge when you come to it :-) Although by that logic i suppose theres nothing wrong with using concat/group_concat...

Comment: I don't think that it won't be a problem. You see, there are limit for posts - 4 posts in one page. And I should add limit for docs too.

Comment: IF you want separate limits you are going to need to restructure your query to use subqueries. Othersiwse you limit is going to apply to the resultset as a flat row... meaning if your limit 4 and you 10 docs attached to a single post your only going to get 1 post record with the first 4 docs attached. It actually might be easier to forget about the join on docs and jsut run a completely sperate query against the post_id's youve fetched something like `SELECT * FROM docs WHERE docs.post_id IN (<list of fetched post_ids>)`, then you can loop over those and assign them to the proper post.

Comment: Ye, I think that gonna be the easiest and the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use old query (and add new fields as name) and do it via php

```
$posts=array();
$lastPostId=-1;
while($nextrow=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    if($nextrow['id']!=$lastPostId){
        $posts[$nextrow['id']]=$nextrow;
        $posts[$nextrow['id']]['docs']=array();
        if(!is_null($nextrow['attachment_id']))
            $posts[$nextrow['id']]['docs']=array('id'=>$nextrow['attachment_id'] ,name => $nextrow['attach_name']...);
    }
    else{
        $posts[$nextrow['id']]['docs'][]=array('id'=>$nextrow['attachment_id'] ,name => $nextrow['attach_name']...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT ...
    GROUP_CONCAT(`docs`.`id`);
...
GROUP BY `posts`.`id`
```

to get 1 entry to 1 post with all id's then `explode`

Comment: This could work but its possibly he could come across the size limit for the contact... especially if he using hashes as part of the data he wants to concat, or if there are just a ton of documents attached to a given post. Its never been an issue for me when ive used this approach but one should be wary.. it might work now... it might not work a year from now :-)

Comment: just for reference... from the manual: The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet.

Comment: @Andomar you think GROUP_CONCAT(`docs`.`name`),GROUP_CONCAT(`docs`.`hashname`) will not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can't push seweral rows into some rows of your query. You can try to join it in way that will provide:

```
article1|article1otherinfo|relateddoc1
article1|article1otherinfo|relateddoc2
article1|article1otherinfo|relateddoc3
article2|article2otherinfo|relateddoc4
article2|article2otherinfo|relateddoc5
article2|article2otherinfo|relateddoc6
```

or concat with CONCAT():

```
article1|article1otherinfo|relateddoc1,relateddoc2,relateddoc3
article2|article2otherinfo|relateddoc4,relateddoc5,relateddoc6
```

And explode for PHP use by some special charactar wich you used to concatenating.

Or just do sub-query for every article for it's related documents